# Can not modify value in JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a question about how to update JavaRDD values.

I have a `JavaRDD<CostedEventMessage>` with message objects containing information about to which partition of kafka topic it should be written to.

I'm trying to change the `partitionId` field of such objects using the following code:

```
rddToKafka = rddToKafka.map(event -> repartitionEvent(event, numPartitions));
```

where the `repartitionEvent` logic is:

```
costedEventMessage.setPartitionId(1);
return costedEventMessage;
```

But the modification does not happen.

Could you please advice why and how to correctly modify values in a JavaRDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark is lazy, so from the code you pasted above it's not clear if you actually performed any action on the JavaRDD (like `collect` or  `forEach`) and how you came to the conclusion that data was not changed.

For example, if you assumed that by running the following code:

```
List<CostedEventMessage> messagesLst = ...;
JavaRDD<CostedEventMessage> rddToKafka = javaSparkContext.parallelize(messagesLst);
rddToKafka = rddToKafka.map(event -> repartitionEvent(event, numPartitions));
```

Each element in `messagesLst` would have partition set to 1, you are wrong.
That would hold true if you added for example:

```
messagesLst = rddToKafka.collect();
```

For more details refer to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations)

Comment: In my case I have to return `JavaRDD<CostedEventMessage>` and there is no possibility to call `collect()`.
Is there any solution that I can use to modify `JavaRDD<CostedEventMessage>`?

Comment: return it to what purpose? What are you doing with the RDD afterwards?

Comment: Is there any other methods I can use to force Spark to make those changes and again get JavaRDD?

Comment: External code uses JavaRDD which I return to out it in kafka topic

Comment: So the external code that uses this RDD would trigger the "modification" by performing an action on it. It's still not clear how you came to conclusion that changes are not applied, I mean - which objects you inspected? You cannot inspect the RDD itself. 
I really suggest you read the documentation

Comment: I came to conclusion that it was not changed because partition to which external code put these messages are the same as before my change:(